# Find middle of X-Axis to place label Swift Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, swift, label

I have a label in Swift that I made programmatically. I am trying to position this label in the middle of the x-axis regardless of the device's screen size. How would I do that?

```
    var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 50))
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 50)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.text = "My label is cool"
    self.view?.addSubview(label)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width and height as follow:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))
    label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 50)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.text = "My label is cool"
    self.view?.addSubview(label)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just the middle of x axis is not enough. You should decide where in the y axis it should go.

Here is an example that puts your label in the middle of x and y (i.e. in the middle of the view):

```
func placeTheLabelAtCenterOfView(view: UIView, withRect rect: CGRect, andText text: String) {
    let label = UILabel(frame: rect)
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 50)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.text = text

    // Disable automatic translation of constraints
    label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    // Create the needed constraints
    let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: label,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.view,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0
    )

    let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: label,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.view,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0
    )

    // Add the subView (before adding the constraints)
    view.addSubview(label)

    // Add the constraints
    view.addConstraints([
        horizontalConstraint,
        verticalConstraint,
        ])
}
```